# Is it possible to make the environment ignore $http_proxy env variable for certain urls?

Tags: bash, proxy, environment-variables, http-proxy

In Firefox, I can set a proxy for all URLs except certain domains.

Is it possible to do the same with the `http_proxy` environmental variable?

That is, could I set another variable to exclude certain URL suffixes?

Answer (score 1):

If by "URL suffixes" you mean certain domain names then you could try setting `no_proxy` variable.

```
export no_proxy="domain1.tld,domain2.tld,domain3.tld"
```